# What is RLPn encoding?

Tags: encoding

I came across a [code](https://github.com/icon-project/goloop/blob/17fc02ed20a3e939c9a962c9fb2cec56c5fdb683/javaee/api/src/java/score/Context.java#L477) snippet where RLPn encoding is mentioned. What is this RLPn encoding and how is it different than RLP?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, because no one might know, try posting at https://github.com/icon-project/goloop/issues

Answer (score 1):

From their codebase:

*RLPn is [RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) with Null (`[0xF8 0x00]`)*

See their [Binary Format](https://github.com/icon-project/goloop/blob/235ee3ea075290a1f15a07b690d26360eef657c2/doc/btp_extension.md#binary-format) docs for details.

> ...how is it different than RLP?

I believe it's an extended RLP that allows certain types to be NULL-able, which isn't natively supported in vanilla RLP.